# Login to other user's account with Devise+Active Admin+Switch User

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to implement [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) gem in my existing rails 3.0.9 application. 
There are two models on my application, they are

1. **User** - for my customer accounts and it **has_one** **Account**
2. **AdminUser** - This was created by ActiveAdmin

I have already enabled devise authentication for `Users` and ActiveAdmin also working pretty much well with `AdminUser`. Now from my Active Admin interface I'd like to select the Accounts and login to those account just like the account owner does. Switch user is working fine but the problem is anyone can simply login to the user accounts now if they know the urls.

http://localhost:3000/switch_user?scope_identifier=user_1

All I need is allow only an AdminUser (i.e if there is an ActiveAdmin session) to access the User's accounts.

This is how my /config/initializers/switch_user.rb looks like

```
SwitchUser.setup do |config|
  config.controller_guard = lambda { |current_user, request| current_admin_user.nil?}
  config.redirect_path = lambda { |request, params| "/dashboard" }
end
```

But I get this error

```
NameError in SwitchUserController#set_current_user

undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user' for main:Object
```

Is there anyway I can access the active admin session?

Code for /config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "MyAppName"
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
end
```

btw in my application controller I haven't created any methods for `authenticate_admin_user` , `current_admin_user` active admin works fine without them.

Comment: I tried almost everything I can think of but still no luck. anyone else please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I found a solution to secure the `switch_user`. All I did is moving the routes inside the admin_users scope

```
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config do
    match '/admin/switch_user', :controller => 'switch_user', :action => 'set_current_user'
  end
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I don't even see the route when I rake routes. Have you tried this on a newer version of activeadmin?

Answer (score 5):

You need modify local `config/initializers/switch_user.rb`:

```
config.controller_guard = lambda { |current_user, request, original_user, controller|
    controller.admin_user_signed_in?
}
```

Original lambda has 2 arguments. 
Just append more (up to 4) and use it.

Don't forget restart rails server :)

Comment: This should be in the switch_user documentation